# How to go back to previous page in asp.net while retaining the previous page data

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am having problem while using onclick="javascript:history.back();" with Aspnet. In the first page i filled some data and click search button it show some results, i click on particular result for its details which navigate to the 2nd page but when i click on custom back button it refresh the page and all data set to initial values,when i use onclick="javascript:history.back();" I get nothing but the page displays "webpage has expired."

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using the BACK button to revert to the previous state of the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732378/using-the-back-button-to-revert-to-the-previous-state-of-the-page)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are using HTTP POST for your search page. 
If you use HTTP GET (putting your parameters in the querystring) - then the browser won't display this message.

This has nothing specifically to do with ASP.NET. It's a (sensible) browser behaviour to prevent you from repeating an action that may have undesirable impacts (for instance, sending two copies of an order)

Comment: Thanks Will for your quick response.It helps me to identify my mistake.