# how to load pages by ajax jquery with history and back/forward buttons support

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

is it possible to use html5 `history api` or `history.js` with ajax function that loads pages dynamically that are in different directories as you can see in the below href like `Browse` `Top_albums` `Top_artists` `Top_lists` `Charts` into a div with an id `main_container` without page reload?
i am newbie to jquery and tried to understand how to implement html5 `history api` with no success.
please any one who knows about these stuff help me. thanks in advance

this is my navigation menu.

```
<nav>
<ul id='menu' class="menu-items">
<li><a  href="Browse/Browse_Page1.php" class="active"><i class="arcd-archive"> </i></br>Browse</a></li>
<li><a href="Top_albums/Top_albums_Page1.php"><i class="arcd-music97"></i></br>Top albums</a></li>
<li><a href="Top_artists/Top_artists_Page1.php" ><i class="arcd-microphone52"></i></br>Top artists</a></li>
<li><a href="Top_lists/Top_lists_Page1.php" ><i class="arcd-numbered8"></i></br>Top lists</a></li>
<li><a href="Charts/Charts_Page1.php" ><i class="arcd-rising9"></i></br>Charts</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

any this is div where i wanted ajax to load new pages.

```
 <div id="main_container"> ajax contents goes here </div>
```

Comment: set cache property to true

Comment: @Simi TKD  can you please give me an example

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29886/how-to-keep-the-browser-history-in-sync-when-using-ajax

Comment: i am now using this function and it works but it uses hashing but i need `html5 history api` so i move forward and backward please help me to achieve this. only back and forward buttons support now i need please visit my this question to answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31553992/how-to-replace-url-hashing-with-html5-history-api