# Get last redirect URL used by ajax & open it if user click browser back button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, pagination

I am using pagination with ajax. If user click on 3rd then I am opening third page using ajax.

If from that page, I go to another page & click on browser back button then page 3rd not opening. It is opening 1st page.

So how can I open 3rd page, if user click on back button

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to keep the browser history in sync when using Ajax?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29886/how-to-keep-the-browser-history-in-sync-when-using-ajax)

Comment: Have you see my answer? What do you say?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`hash`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hash.asp) (or [`pushState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) method in modern browsers) to "save" the last pagination state. When you load the data, take the page from the `hash`.

Here is **primitive** sample. You can see that if you click on the links to move to another page, then you turn back (using back button or whatever) it's present  the previews items.

**How it works?**

Whenever you click on the links, let's say the first link, which his `href` attribute is `#1` the event `hashchange` was fired. Now, you can read the value of the `hash` by using `location.hash` (the `replace` method uses for remove the `#` symbol). Now, if you click on the second link then click **back** the `hashchage` event fired again and so on..

```js
// set data
var data = [],
    numOfPages = 5;

for (var i = 0; i < numOfPages; i++) {
  data.push([1 + '' + i, 2 + '' + i, 3 + '' + i, 4 + '' + i, 5 + '' + i]);
}

// paging method
var list = document.querySelector('ul');
function getPage(pageNum) {
  !pageNum && (pageNum = 0);
  var html = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < data[pageNum].length; i++) {
    html += ('<li>' + data[pageNum][i] + '</li>');
  }
  list.innerHTML = html;
}

getPage();

// generate pageing buttons
var paging = document.querySelector('#paging'),
    pagingHTML = '';

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  pagingHTML += ('<a href="#' + i +'">' + i + '</a>');
}

paging.innerHTML = pagingHTML;

// listen to changes in the hash
window.addEventListener('hashchange', function() {
  var pageIndex = location.hash.replace('#', '');
  getPage(pageIndex);
});
```

```css
a {
  display:inline-block;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul></ul>
<div id="paging"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue by using html5 Local Storage.

When using click on any page then that page no, I am storing in local storage. So if user go to another page & click on back button, then I am getting last page no that he clicked & I am getting those records.

So by use Local Storage, problem is solved.